# How to find discretezation error of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, error-tracking

Is there a way to find out how large the truncation, round-off, and other errors that occur from discretizing a differential equation are while using the default settings in NDSolve? Or would I have to explicitly ask Mathematica to solve the problem using 4th order Runge-Kutta, Adams, etc and find the errors myself.

I did find this link: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CheckTheResultsOfNDSolve.html

helpful, but I am wondering what other methods are available.

Comment: The last part (Spatial Error Estimates) of [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html#2081642391) may be helpful?